# Extract html contents from fields and save them a file for every record with powershell

Tags: html, sql-server, powershell

I have a SQL Server table with this structure :

```
CODE  | DATA
------+---------------------------
x3456 | html body ... ecc ecc
x3457 | html body ... ecc ecc...
```

The column `data` contains a single full html page.

Expected result:

I want to generate in a proper folder  one file for each record that contains the html code extracted from field.

**eg:**

```
temp\
x3456.html
x3457.html 
ecc ecc...
```

I want  to achieve this via powershell script .. it is possible?

Some examples?

Thanks

Comment: [Some examples](https://www.google.com/#safe=off&q=mssql+export+records+as+separate+files).

Answer (score 0):

I completely stole this code from a two different google searches, first was "query sql with powershell", second was "powershell write to files".  Copy, paste, done.

```
function sql($sqlText, $database = "master", $server = ".")
{
    write-host $server
    $connection = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection("Data Source=$server;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=$database");
    $cmd = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($sqlText, $connection);

    $connection.Open();
    $reader = $cmd.ExecuteReader()

    $results = @()
    while ($reader.Read())
    {
        $row = @{}
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $reader.FieldCount; $i++)
        {
            $row[$reader.GetName($i)] = $reader.GetValue($i)
        }
        $results += new-object psobject -property $row            
    }
    $connection.Close();

    $results
}

$results = sql -sqltext "select * from mssqi" -database "test" -server "svr-sql-01"

foreach ($row in $results)
{
    $stream = [System.IO.StreamWriter] $row.Code
    $stream.WriteLine($row.Data)
    $stream.Close()
}
```